# Jsoup get Product Description

Tags: html, parsing, jsoup

I would like to get the Product Description of this Website:
https://www.real.de/product/346010948/?id_item_promotion=620332

I think I need  
But I have no clue how to parse it.

This is my parsing code

```
@Override
public Product getDescriptionByReal(Product product) {
    String completeUrl = "https://www.real.de/product/" + product.getPlattformProductId() + "/";
    try {
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(completeUrl).get();
        Elements description = document.select("div#prodct-data");
        product.setDesc(description.text());
        return product;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        product.setDesc(e.getMessage());
        return product;
    }
}
```

If i try "document.select("div.rd-product-description__text");" or "document.select("div#prodct-data")" i get nothing,
if i change it up to "document.select("div"); i get not the data i want.

Comment: "I think I need But I have no clue how to parse it."  I forgot to mention that i need <div class="rd-product-description__text" </div>...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product description is loaded asynchronously after the main document. Jsoup can access ony the document before Javascript modifications. Using chrome debugger I found the URL from where it's fetched. You can download this JSON:
https://www.real.de/pdp-test/api/v1/346010948/product-description/
and parse it to get the description. Jsoup can't parse JSON so you'll have to use other library or use simple regular expression to get the part between `<div>` and `</div>`.